# Vagrant provision with salt: The function "state.highstate" is running

Tags: vagrant, salt-stack, vagrantfile

When I use salt to provision my vagrant box, the following output is returned:

```
Calling state.highstate... (this may take a while)
local:
Data failed to compile:
----------
The function "state.highstate" is running as PID 2998 and was started at  with jid req
```

This means I can't see the results of the highstate command. This is my salt config in Vagrantfile:

```
  config.vm.provision :salt do |salt|
  salt.minion_key = "srv/etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem"
  salt.minion_pub = "srv/etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pub"
  salt.minion_config = "srv/etc/salt/minion"
  salt.run_highstate = true
  salt.verbose = true
  salt.colorize = true
  salt.log_level = 'all'
```

Am I doing something wrong? I would like to be able to see the output of the highstate command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

The minion configuration file had the startup_states: key set to highstate so the highstate command was run when the minion was booted. To fix the issue, I commented out the line in the configuration and now everything works!